# ¿Cómo rebindear un GridView con ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, gridview

Buen día, quisiera que me pudieran apoyar para poder rebindear un GridView en C#, la primera vez que carga la página lo bindeo, después cuando hago click en un botón y ejecuto una operación con ajax que me regresa un DataTable para volver a bindear el Grid, pero el Grdi no se bindeo con los nuevos datos, se queda igual.

La primera vez lo bindeo

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                CheckData();
            }    
        }
```

Cuando se hace click en un botón ejecuto un método llamado GetDate por vía ajax que hace lo siguiente:

```
   [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static  string GetDate(string valor)
        {
            Default df = new Default();
            df.AddData();
            return valor;           
        }

        private Boolean AddData()
        {
            Boolean vlBlnResult = false;
            List<SqlParameter> vlParamCol = new List<SqlParameter>();
            XmlDocument vXmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNode vlXmlParametros = vXmlDocument.AppendChild(vXmlDocument.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "", "Parametros", ""));

            string vlStrError = string.Empty;
            List<SqlParameter> vlParam = new List<SqlParameter>();
            string vInStrSpName = "";

            vInStrSpName = "spGetData";
            vlParam.Add(new SqlParameter("@Prefijo", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Input, Value = "ACM" });
            bool vlBlnTmp = clsConectDB.fgTblRetCommand(vInStrSpName, ref vlParam, ref gblTblDatos, new clsConectDB.StructConn { ConnectKey = vmstrAmbiente, SpecialConectionString = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vmstrAmbiente) ? vmStrBDConLocal : "") }, ref vlStrError);
            BindGrid();            
            return vlBlnResult;
        }

        private bool BindGrid()
        {
            Boolean Result = false;

            Grid.DataSource = gblTblDatos;
            Grid.DataBind();                       
            return Result;
        }
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `gblTblDatos` y qué hace `CheckData();`?

Comment: donde estas refrescando la grilla?? porque si es una llamada ajax, no viaja toda la pagina, es probable que la grilla ni se entere que hubo un cambio sobre ella.

Comment: Que tal @Mauricio Arias Olave,  `gblTblDatos` es una variable de tipo dataTable y `CheckData();` es una función que bindea el Grid la primera vez que se carga la página.

Comment: @gbianchi en si bindeo el Grid con la función "BindGrid", pero no se si tenga que refrescar antes el grid de otra forma. o limpiarlo y volverlo a bindear.

Comment: Si deseas rebindear el GridView con ajax, creo que deberías colocar un botón oculto y con ajax disparas el evento onclick. Mira esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604506/4092887).

Comment: @Mauricio Arias Olave, vere esa respuesta, pero en si tengo un botón que es el que ejecuta la operación vía ajax.

Comment: En diseño tengo un botón declarado de la siguiente manera:

`<input type="button" id="btnGetDate" value="Show Date" onclick="AddRow()"/>`

Y mando a ejecutar ajax:

`function AddRow(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}`

Comment: @JulioMorenoDev, para que funcione según lo que te mostré en el enlace anterior, el botón debe ser de tipo ASP.NET; el tuyo es HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer el rebind y actualizar los datos tanto en el servidor como en el navegador del cliente, tendrías que meter el **GridView** en un **UpdatePanel**, puedes leer la información desde la misma página de Microsoft: [Introducción al control UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx).

Básicamente este control te permite actualizar la parte de la página dentro del mismo sin necesidad de enviar la página completa al servidor ni recargar la página, que es lo que estás buscando.